# granting permissions in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I am logged in with a windows authentication account which is sa. Trying to grant CONTROL SERVER permission to myself, and shows this error

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

default sa is disabled. If I am the only sa in the server how to grant my login that permission in order to do some operation which require that.
[image]
Thanks for support in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am logged in with a windows authentication account which is sa

`sa` is a SQL Login, so I'm assuming you mean that your Windows Login is a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role.

Members of the sysadmin fixed server role already have all the rights that would be granted by having CONTROL SERVER permissions, so you should not need any additional grants.  If you do need that permission (say, for instance, a software installation checks it explicitly), the trick is to impersonate `sa` while you grant it to yourself.  Eg

```
execute as login = 'sa'

  grant control server to [yourdomain\you]

revert
```